# How to find active brush in Image Editor context?

Tags: python, scripting

At the minute I use `bpy.data.brushes['TexDraw']` in an operator, but can I find the currently active brush in UV/Image Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it

```
context.tool_settings.image_paint.brush
```

Comment: Good find. The [latest documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79b/info_api_reference.html) (2.79b) states 'bpy.context.brush' or 'bpy.context.sculpt.brush' (in sculpting mode) which don't work.